# Codeigniter how to set constant value dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i have set a constant value in my config/constants.php file

```
define('CONST_VAR', 'abc');
```

Now can I change the constant value on the run while using my app ? if so, how do I do it ?

Comment: I am not a php guy, but from my experience in other languages, constants cannot be changed at run time.

Comment: A constant is called constant because its value is constant. Sounds plausible, doesn't it?

Comment: Do you want to change value or set value only once with variable?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `define` method to make it `CONSTANT` use just use variable which will be global variable for you like this, in `config/constants.php`

```
 $globalVar = 'abc';
```

Now you can use this variable `$globalVar` anywhere and also change it.

Another option is by `Sesstion`

```
$this->session->session_item = 'abc';
```

Comment: where do I write the $globarvar = 'abc' ? in the constants file, tried but still can't use the variable in my controllers.

Comment: inside `config/constants.php`

Comment: still can't use the $globalVar in my controllers